# Update field the_geom name city in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, geocoding

With "update table set the_geom = cdb_latlng (lat , lon ) " I update the_geom field through latitude and longitude, but I also interested to know if there is any chance that instead of passing a latitude and longitude , pass a string is 'Madrid' for example, and you will then update the field the_geom with the coordinates of Madrid.

---

Con "update table set the_geom = cdb_latlng(lat, lon)" actualizo el campo the_geom a través de latitud y longitud , pero tambien me interesaria saber si hay alguna opción de que en vez de pasarle una latitud y una longitud, pasarle un string que sea 'Madrid' por ejemplo y que te te haga update del campo the_geom con las coordenadas de Madrid.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no internal function in order to call to the georeferencing process, so the only possibility is to add a column with the city names and then georeference the table (Options > Georeference) in order to get the coordinates - aka, in order to geocode your file.

Basically, you can geocode your table through the user interface by clicking on the required buttons but you cannot geocode the table programatically by using CartoDB functions as at the moment they're not publicly available.

[This tutorial on georeferencing](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference.html) may be useful for you or other users in order to geocode a table that contains geospatial information but it hasn't been translated to the map yet.

Comment: I am in need of geocoding my table programmatically by using CartoDB functions. I would like to know now those functions are available to public.

Comment: These functions are not public right now, but if you keep it a secret, we're *right now* working on it ;-) You will know when it's available, as we will be working in documentation and so on. Be patient!